# How to fix VirtualBox redhat-7 eth0 ONBOOT=no connectivity issue with vboxmange tools?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, redhat, pack

I am creating virtualbox redhat box with packer with the template attached below. Everything is fine except that when the host is created and rebooted, the eth0 network adapter does not start as it is created with ONBOOT=no in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts. However, if I open the UI of the box and manually trigger ifup eth0, it starts fine, ssh becomes available and the process completes as expected. However, I need to use it in a jenkins pipeline so there is no option someone can go and start the network interface manually. The question, is there any way to change the ONBOOT option to yes for the network adapter with virtualbox manage commands, or trigger the ifup eth0 command somehow. Either option may solve the problem.

```
  {
  "variables": {
    "build_base": ".",
    "isref_machine":"create-ova-caf",
    "build_name":"virtual-box-jenkins",
    "output_name":"packer-virtual-box",
    "disk_size":"40000",
    "ram":"1024",
    "disk_adapter":"ide"
  },  
  "builders":[
        {   
          "name": "{{user `build_name`}}",
          "type": "virtualbox-iso",
          "guest_os_type": "Other_64",
          "iso_url": "rhelis74_1710051533.iso",
          "iso_checksum": "",
          "iso_checksum_type": "none",
          "hard_drive_interface":"{{user `disk_adapter`}}",
          "ssh_username": "root",
          "ssh_password": "Secret1.0",
          "shutdown_command": "shutdown -P now",
          "guest_additions_mode":"disable",
          "boot_wait": "3s",
          "boot_command": [ "auto<enter>"],
          "ssh_timeout": "40m",
          "headless":
          "true",
          "vm_name": "{{user `output_name`}}",
                    "disk_size": "{{user `disk_size`}}",
          "output_directory":"{{user `build_base`}}/output-{{build_name}}",
          "format": "ovf",
          "vrdp_bind_address": "0.0.0.0",
          "vboxmanage": [
            ["modifyvm", "{{.Name}}","--nictype1","virtio"],
            ["modifyvm", "{{.Name}}","--memory","{{ user `ram`}}"]
          ],
          "skip_export":true,
          "keep_registered": true
        }   
  ],  
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type":"shell",
      "inline": ["ls"]

    }
  ]

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the network interface boot settings to onboot=yes, we need to create an anaconda kickstart script or copy one from an existing machine and change the configurations in it and pass it as

```
 "boot_command": [ "<esc><wait>",
        "vmlinuz initrd=initrd.img net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 ",
        "ks=hd:fd0:/anaconda-ks.cfg",
        "<enter>"
  ],
```

and in anaconda file

```
network  --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0 --onboot=on --ipv6=auto --activate
```

Comment: when you face the same issue and kill your self several hours and then check stackoverflow and find your own post :)